# Injecting IntegrationTest via plugin into SBT breaks dependency classpath

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a simple plugin that injects `IntegrationTest` configuration into every project:

```
object SensibleConfiguration extends AutoPlugin {
  override def trigger: PluginTrigger = allRequirements
  override def requires: Plugins = JvmPlugin
  override def projectConfigurations: Seq[Configuration] = Seq(IntegrationTest)
  override def projectSettings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = Defaults.itSettings
}
```

If I remove the `.configs(IntegrationTest)` from `build.sbt`, I can confirm configuration is still present. However, dependencies marked for this scope are no longer included during test runs. This is true, even if I leave `.configs(IntegrationTest)`.
For example:

```
"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "8.0.16" % IntegrationTest
```

is still present in `it:dependencyClasspath` (as seen on `sbt "show it:dependencyClasspath"`) but the test don't have the lib on classpath.

Tried with versions `1.2.8`, `1.3.3` and `1.3.8`.

What am I missing?